# How to change graphql endpoint url name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm just start using graphql with apollo client, I have graphql server setup and is running localhost:4000, and here is my client

index.js

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

blog.js

```
const GET_BLOG = gql`
  {
    post(id:"5ab2b46d941953bf614e2617") {
        title
        body
        user {
            name
            email
        }
    }
  }
 <Query query={GET_BLOG}>...</Query>
```

I got everything working, my question is there way I can change the graphql endpoint url name, so instead of graphql, can I have something like /graphql/post, /graphql/user, I have the scheme in graphql server, but if I do two call, it will just return two /graphql in network tab

Answer (score 2):

```
SERVER.applyMiddleware({
  app: APP, 
  path: '/newEndPoint'
});
```

Set path attribute within applyMiddleWare Options object. Now visit 
`localhost:<port>/newEndPoint` for the grap

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, graphql only use one endpoint url name, in your case is http://localhost:4000/graphql , if you want separated endpoint, it is just like REST routing